# Submitting Soap XML using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, web-services

When using SoapUI 5.3, I can submit a request successfully using the request editor (to a web service).  I am attempting to submit the file using Excel VBA but am not able to determine if this completed properly or not.

I am using the VBA code below, but have only 1 days experience with XML. I think the problem may be in the prolog or header, but I am not sure what this should be as there is no header on the request in SoapUI.  I have the reference to Microsoft XML 6.0 set.

```
Sub SendXMLtoSAA()
    Dim myHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim myDom As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim myXML As String

    ''myDom.LoadXML (myXML)
    myDom.Load "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.xml"
    myHTTP.Open "post", myServer, False

    myHTTP.send (myDom.XML)
    MsgBox myHTTP.responseText    
End Sub
```

I added `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` to the start of the XML code but no matter what values are in the fields, I get the same `responsetext` and do not know if it has been 'Posted' properly and if the values are acceptable.  Should I be looking at some other value?

**EDIT**:  It appears that the `myHTTP.responseText` is showing the original webservice XML.

**RE-Edit**: This is because I had not removed wsdl from the server link.

The other code I had posted below was incomplete and turns out to be unnecessary, so I have removed it so that others do not get confused by it.

Thanks to all who had a look at this for me.

Comment: I suggest that you install a sniffer of some kind (Wireshark or something else) and look at what you are sending from SoapUI vs from Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I said I had no experience with XML and what was wrong just goes to prove it.

For the server, I had it ending in `...ls.php?wsdl&test` but I should have removed the wsdl from that and had just `...ls.php?test`

The other sticking point was the variable type for myHTTP.
I had this as `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` but I believe this blocks the response as a security measure for cookies.  After amending to `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`, it looks like that does the trick.

Comment: Level one experience gained!